# Why I am not getting OutOfBounds exception (like Java one) or any other error in C when I violate array size constraints?

Tags: c, arrays

I am curious about below code in C

```
int main(){

        int arr[10];
        *(arr+120) = 5;
        int *px = arr;
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; *px != 5; px++){
          i++;
        }

        printf("%d", i);
}
```

This code produced output of 120.
Our array is said to hold 10 items. How can I assign some value for index 120, run loop and get my value if there potentially should be some kind of error. Probably I am not getting some C language specifics. In java I would get OutOfBounds exception....
Please, help to clarify it. Thank you!

Comment: In C, it's up to you to do the checking for that sort of thing. The compiler isn't going to check for you.

Comment: C doesn't do array bounds checking. Further, C doesn't have exceptions.

Comment: you're allowed to shoot yourself in the foot in all sorts of fantastical way in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not check array bounds, and the code accessing out-of-array elements is undefined behaviour, which means that anything may happen - including the result you got.

Comment: oh, wow.. it is tricky. Thanks